# Pandas Rename Columns

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I am trying to rename my columns with the previous column name with a number on the end to make the columns unique. Is there a way to achieve this?

CurrentDF:

```
Reconnaissance      Unnamed: 1          Resource Development    Unnamed: 3      Initial Access          Unnamed: 5  
Active Scanning     Scanning IP Blocks  Acquire Infrastructure  Botnet          Drive-by Compromise         NaN
```

Desired:

```
Reconnaissance      Reconnaissance_1        Resource Development    Resource Development_1      Initial Access          Initial Access_1
Active Scanning     Scanning IP Blocks  Acquire Infrastructure  Botnet                      Drive-by Compromise         NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's every second column that needs renaming, you can use:

```
df = df.rename(columns = {df.columns[i]: f"{df.columns[i-1]}_1" for i in range(1, len(df.columns),2)})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Series from the columns (because `Index` objects have no `ffill` method, which is useful here). Then determine which columns start with `Unnamed`, mask them and use a cumcount to figure out what number to add onto the end (in the case of possibly multiple consecutive Unnamed: columns) and use `ffill` to get the previous column label that didn't start with 'Unnamed'. Assign the columns with this Series.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Reconnaissance', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Resource Development',    
                           'Unnamed: 3', 'Initial Access', 'Unnamed: 5'],
                  data=1, index=[0])
```

#### Code

```
s = pd.Series(df.columns)

s = s.mask(s.str.startswith('Unnamed:'))
s = (s.ffill() 
     + s.groupby(s.notnull().cumsum()).cumcount().astype(str).radd('_').replace('_0', ''))

df.columns = s
```

---

```
print(df)

   Reconnaissance  Reconnaissance_1  Resource Development  Resource Development_1  Initial Access  Initial Access_1
0               1                 1                     1                       1               1                 1
```

---

And here's another example to show how this behaves with less regularly spaced 'Unnamed:' columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'b', 'c', 'Unnamed: 3'],
                  data=[np.arange(6)], index=[0])

#### Same code as above

print(df)
   a  a_1  a_2  b  c  c_1
0  0    1    2  3  4    5
```

Answer (score 0):

To rename all columns at once you can do the following:

```
df.columns = [col1, col2, col3]
```